# Finding the most efficient data structure to create an index file

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures, big-o, video-capture

I have a video file, which consists of many successive frames of binary data. Each frame has also a unique timestamp (which is NOT its sequential number in file, but rather a value, provided by the camera at the recording time). On the other hand, I've got an API function which retrieves that frame based on the sequential number of that frame. To make things a bit more complicated - I have a player, who is provided with the timestamp, and should get the binary data for that frame.

Another sad thing here: timestamps are NOT sequential. They can be sequential, but it is not guaranteed, as a wraparound may occur around max unsigned short size.
So a sequence of timestamps could be either 
54567, 54568, ... , 65535, 65536 , ... or
54567, 54568, ..., 65535, 0, 1, ...

So it might look like the following:

```
Frame 0
timestamp 54567
binary data
........
Frame 1
timestamp 54569
binary data
........
Frame 2
timestamp 54579
binary data
.
.
.
Frame n
timestamp m
binary data

0 <= n <= 65536 (MAX_UNSIGNED_SHORT)
0 <= m <= MAX_UNSIGNED_INT
```

The clip player API should be able to get the binary frame by the timestamp. However, internally, I can get the frame only by its frame sequential number. So if I am asked for timestamp `m`, I need to iterate over `n` frames, to find the frame with timestamp `m`.

To optimize it, I chose to create an index file, which would give me a match between timestamp and the frame sequential number. And here is my question:

Currently my index file is composed of binary pairs of size `2*sizeof(unsigned int)`, which contains timestamp and frame sequential number. Player later on creates from that file `stl map` with `key==timestamp`, `value==frame sequential number`.

Is there any way to do it more efficiently? Should I create my index file as a dump of some data structure, so it could later be loaded into memory by the clip player while opening the clip, so I would have an O(1) access to frames? Do you have other suggestions?

UPD:

I have updated the names and requirements (timestamps are not necessarily sequential, and frames num bounded by MAX_UNSIGNED_SHORT value). Also wanted to thank everyone who already took the time and gave an answer. The interpolation search is an interesting idea, although I never tried it myself. I guess the question would be the delta between `O(1)` and `O(log log N)` in runtime.

Comment: there is no correlation between the two (other than that they're both strictly increasing) ?

Comment: I'm guessing "frame index" is a timestamp? Doesn't strictly affect the answers you'll get, but the names are a bit clumsy as is. You might find some useful information in the open [Matroska specification](http://www.matroska.org/technical/index.html)

Comment: "frame index" could be thought of as a "timestamp". I agree these aren't the best names chosen :(

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that we should be able to make the following assumptions:
a) the video file itself will not be modified after it is created
b) the player may want to find successive frames i.e. when it is doing normal playback
c) the player may want to find random frames i.e. when it is doing FF, REW or skip by or to chapter

Given this, why not just do a HashMap associating the Frame Id and the Frame Index?  You can create that once, the player can read it and then can do an easy and time bounded look up of the requested Frame.

Comment: You mean `std::unordered_map`, not `HashMap`.  Not a bad idea, although, if the number of frames is small, then the hash function may cost more than searching a binary tree or sorted array.

Comment: That's a fair point but the number of frames is typically quite large (I used to work in Motorola's Video On Demand group).  Depends of course if you're streaming 10-30 second ads or 2 hour movies :-)

Comment: Most of my work in image analysis is on movies of cells that are 200 frames or less (longer and the signal usually bleaches out).  There are, sadly, few perfect and universal solutions.  The interpolation search suggested by @JerryCoffin does seems like a good idea for this particular data.

Comment: Number of frames currently won't be more than 65536

Answer (score 0):

There are a series of tradeoffs to make here.

Your index file is already a dump of a data structure: an array.  If you don't plan on often inserting or deleting frames, and keep this array in a sorted order, it's easy to do a binary search (using `std::binary_search`) on the array.  Insertion and deletion take O(N), but searching is still O(log N).  The array will occupy less space in memory, and will be faster to read and write from your index file.

If you're doing a lot of inserting and removing frames, then coverting to a `std::map` structure will give you better performance.  If the number of frames is large, or you want to store more metadata with them, you might want to look at a [B-tree structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), or just use an embedded database like [Sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or [BerkeleyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/overview/index.html).  Both of these implement B-tree indexing and are well-tested pieces of code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply store the frame data in an array where indices represent frame numbers. Then create a hash map from camera indices to frame numbers. You can get the frame belonging to either a frame number or camera index in O(1) while barely using more memory than your current approach.

Alternatively, you can maintain an array, indexed by frame number, that stores a (camera index, data) pair and perform a O(log n) binary search on it when you need to access it by camera index. This takes advantage of the fact that the camera indices are sorted.

In C++'s standard library, hash maps are available as `std::unordered_map` (if you compiler/STL supports them, which might not be the case since they have only recently been added to the C++ standard), although the tree-based `std::map` (with O(log n) lookup) is probably good enough for this purpose.

A binary search implementation is available as `std::binary_search`.